# modify sql lite for creating new query

Tags: mysql, sqlite

```
create TABLE users(
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
userName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

create TABLE roles
(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
role VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)
```

The `users_roles` table should contain the mapping between each user and their roles. Each user
can have many roles, and each role can have many users.
Modify the provided SQLite create table statement in MySQL so that:
● Only users from the users table can exist within users_roles.
● Only roles from the roles table can exist within users_roles.
● A user can only have a specific role once.

```
CREATE TABLE users_roles (
userId INTEGER,
roleId INTEGER
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We're not a [code writing service](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Please, do not post your assignments here, rather show some efforts!

Answer (score 1):

In this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE users_roles (
  userId INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
  roleId INTEGER REFERENCES roles(id),
  PRIMARY KEY(userId, roleId)
);
```

the column `userId` is defined to reference the column `id` of the table `users`,
the column `roleId` is defined to reference the column `id` of the table `roles`,
the combination of `userId` and `roleId` is defined as the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table so any combination can exist only once.
In SQLite keep in mind that you have to enable foreign key constraint support by setting:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qjESbC6hQ8KyF7vzsSuwLb/0).
You can find more [here](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).